# Leave tomorrow or leave for tomorrow

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I need a break tomorrow. What should I say to my boss?

1. Sir, I need a leave tomorrow.
2. Sir, I need a leave *for* tomorrow.

Please help me out.

Comment: Both are acceptable if you're going to use ***leave*** as a "countable" noun (effectively meaning "a certificate of authorisation for a specific period of leave", a definition that won't necessarily be in the dictionary). But you could use it as an *uncountable* noun (a definition that should be in *every* dictionary) by simply discarding the article *(**a**)*. Personally, I think the uncountable usage *also* works with or without the preposition, but opinions may differ.

Comment: I would understand *I need **a** leave [for] tomorrow* as very specifically asking the addressee to ***complete any and all necessary paperwork*** to allow me to take tomorrow off work. But *without* the article, I'm just asking for the day off - perhaps in a very informal workplace environment where they don't even keep a formal record of time taken off work.